# Open source calendar with day view and 15-minute increments?

Tags: php, open-source, calendar

I am looking for an open source(php/mysql) calendar that can provide day-view along with 15-minute increments(events). Do you know if there is anything like this available(and perhaps with an admin interface)? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "google this for me", though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/163321

Comment: Of course, but since i don't find anything in Google i thought i could ask stackoverflow community in case someone had an idea or past experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [DHTMLX Scheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) in the past. It's a javascript cross-platform calendar/scheduler. And yes it has connectors for mysql.